# Is it possible to pass a variable to a command inside ` `

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I was hoping someone on here can advise...

I was wondering is it possible to pass a variable to a command inside back ticks, like the lufslist command shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash

    while active_now
        do
              if [ $active_now == no ]
              then
                 while read zonename
                 do
                       ...

                 done < <(`lufslist $be_name`)
              fi
        done < <(lustatus | sed '1,3d' | awk '{print $3}')
```

I think/hope I'm reasonably close with my above attempt and maybe I'm just missing quotes or brackets of some sort?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the backticks? Why not just `done < <(lufslist "$be_name")`?

Comment: You got the syntax correct for `lustatus`, how is it you couldn't see that it's the same for `lufslist`?

Comment: Thanks folks! As to why I was using backticks - I'm not entirely sure, (still relatively new to scripting) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! You can use:

```
while read zonename
do
...
done < <(lufslist "$be_name")
```

Note the difference between yours

```
done < <(`lufslist $be_name`)
```

and

```
done < <(lufslist "$be_name")
```

the `()` makes the command to be executed in a subshell, so you do not have to use the ` character to call it.

Also, it is always good to call your variables enclosed in double quotes: `lufslist "$be_name"`.

#### Example

```
$ info="1 month ago"
$ while read a; do echo $a; done < <(date -d"$info")
Wed Sep 18 15:00:59 CEST 2013
```

Comment: Many thanks for the swift and concise explanation fedorqui. But why the need to use " " when calling variables - or is it just good practice?

Comment: It is a good practice that will help you avoid strange problems in many cases. See for example http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html